# Как правильно выделить сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, синтаксический-разбор

Как правильно выделить сказуемое в предложении "Он ходил босой и без шляпы"?
БОСОЙ и БЕЗ ШЛЯПЫ входит в состав сказуемого или это обстоятельство?

Какая грамматическая основа в предложении "Старик Тарас был высокого роста, с окладистой седой бородой и строгими большими серыми глазами"?

Answer (score 1):

Он **ходил босой и без шляпы**. Составное именное сказуемое, знаменательная связка "ходил" со значением движения.

Старик Тарас **был высокого роста, с** окладистой седой **бородой и** строгими большими **серыми глазами**. Составное именное сказуемое, незнаменательная связка "был"